# Possible to have mutiple rows for each post/page in the admin table listing?

Tags: dashboard

I have a number of custom fields being displayed in the post list page of Admin Dashboard. My post titles are kind of long, and coupled with so many additional fields is making the table feel crowded.

Is it possible to break this up so it's a single full width row containing the post title and below that another row containing all the other fields.

Forgive to rough mock up, but hopefully this will give you an idea of what I am after.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may need to play around with CSS a bit. But for me following CSS does the trick.

Basically

1. Increase the `height` of each row.
2. Shift all cells (`td`, `th`) down a bit (using `padding-top`)
3. Reset the `padding-top` for Title column and `position` it `absolute`ly with appropriate `left` and `right` values.

Hope that helps

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_style');
function my_custom_style() {
    echo '<style>
    .type-post {
        height: 100px;
    }

    .type-post td, 
    .type-post th, 
    .type-post .fixed .column-comments {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }

    .type-post .column-title.page-title {
        padding-top: 0px;
        left: 35px;
        right: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    }
    </style>';
}
```

Alternatively you can put the CSS in external file and include it like:

```
function admin_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```

Note that its '**admin**_enqueue_scripts' and not the standard 'wp_enqueue_scripts'

Comment: +10 for you, i try your answer and it looks like what Louis W needs.